# What does Subversion use for its CA list?

Tags: macos, ssl, svn, trusted-root-ca

I'm using SVN on Mac OS X. Often, when I checkout something from SourceForge, I am presented with:

```
$ svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cryptopp/code/trunk/c5 cryptopp-ecies
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.code.sf.net:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.code.sf.net
 - Valid: from Thu, 16 Apr 2015 00:00:00 GMT until Sun, 15 May 2016 23:59:59 GMT
 - Issuer: GeoTrust Inc., US
 - Fingerprint: 1f:7b:73:d5:cf:71:18:76:d5:23:f3:07:c9:2f:f5:4a:52:67:0f:68
```

OpenSSL's `s_client` shows the topmost CA is *Equifax Secure Certificate Authority*:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect svn.code.sf.net:443 -showcerts
...
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=Dice Career Solutions/OU=code.sf.net/CN=*.code.sf.net
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

*Equifax Secure Certificate Authority* ***is*** present in OS X's Keychain:

[image]

So I'm not quite sure why I am being prompted by Subversion.

**Question**: what does Subversion use for its CA list?

---

This is Apple's 1.7.10 version of SVN (and not Brew or Macports):

```
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)
   compiled Jan 15 2014, 11:22:16
```

Apple's `man` page for SVN only describes the program in one paragraph. It does not even bother detailing switches.

Answer (score 6):

By default svn client doesn't use any certificates. You have two options:

**1.**

Download latest mozilla CA certificates `ca-bundle.crt` file from the link on [cURL webpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

Find svn config file called `servers` in your home directory: `~/.subversion/servers`. Create the file and `.subversion` folder if they don't exist.

Add path to the certificates bundle in `servers` config `global` section:

```
[global]
ssl-authority-files = /path/to/the/ca-bundle.crt
```

**2.**

Install CA certificates for OpenSSL and add following line to your `servers` config file in `global` section:

```
[global]
ssl-trust-default-ca = yes
```

Initially I thought that the second option doesn't work on OS X but I tested it and it actually works.

Comment: Thanks @baf. I'm interested in learning what Apple's subversion uses for its list, not how to replace it. Subversion's message is *"The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority"*, which tells me its got a list and *Equifax Secure Certificate Authority* is not on it. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @jww It doesn't use any "list". It depends on openssl certificates and openssl doesn't install any certificates by default. If you install certificates and set `ssl-trust-default-ca = yes` it actually works. I updated my answer.

Comment: Option #1 works for Linux as well.  I have not tested #2