# How to instruct SVN print its CA list?

Tags: ssl, svn, trusted-root-certificates, trusted-root-ca

This is related to [What does Subversion use for its CA list?](https://superuser.com/q/903263).

I want to have SVN tell me the CAs its using. `svn help` does not appear to discuss it (but I may have missed it, since its not obvious in the list of sub commands below).

How do I instruct subversion to print its CA list?

---

```
$ svn help
usage: svn <subcommand> [options] [args]
Subversion command-line client, version 1.7.10.
Type 'svn help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Type 'svn --version' to see the program version and RA modules
  or 'svn --version --quiet' to see just the version number.

Most subcommands take file and/or directory arguments, recursing
on the directories.  If no arguments are supplied to such a
command, it recurses on the current directory (inclusive) by default.

Available subcommands:
   add
   blame (praise, annotate, ann)
   cat
   changelist (cl)
   checkout (co)
   cleanup
   commit (ci)
   copy (cp)
   delete (del, remove, rm)
   diff (di)
   export
   help (?, h)
   import
   info
   list (ls)
   lock
   log
   merge
   mergeinfo
   mkdir
   move (mv, rename, ren)
   patch
   propdel (pdel, pd)
   propedit (pedit, pe)
   propget (pget, pg)
   proplist (plist, pl)
   propset (pset, ps)
   relocate
   resolve
   resolved
   revert
   status (stat, st)
   switch (sw)
   unlock
   update (up)
   upgrade

Subversion is a tool for version control.
```